# Is there an adjustment to the Clopper-Pearson CI for stratified random samples?

Tags: sampling

Using the basic Clopper-Pearson formula, I have calculated a confidence interval for a stratified random sample, but it is my understanding that an assumption of Clopper-Pearson is random sampling. Is there an adjustment that can be made for stratified random sampling?